# Landscape orientation of a single viewController in iphone app

Tags: ios, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I need all the views of my iphone app are in portrait mode except one.

I have a list view controller (view 1) that show a detail view (view 2) when clicked.
On the detail view I have a button that triggers a modal segue that should show a view in landscape mode (view 3).

In XCode, I have set orientation to Portrait for view 1 and 2, I have set landscape for view 3.

When the app is launched, view 1 is displayed in portrait mode but when I change the orientation it switches to landscape where I need it to remain in portrait.

When I click view 2's button, the view 3 is displayed in portrait mode (where this is the only one I need to have in landscape).

View 1 and 2 have:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

View 3 has:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
}
```

What the missing configuration to have view 1 and view 2 always in portrait, and view 3 always in landscape ?

**EDIT**

I finally left the application orientation in portrait only and used the notification event to rotate the view I need to have in landscape. That is working pretty good like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running under iOS 6 then `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` has been deprecated. You should use `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` and `shouldAutorotate` methods.

Have a look at the iOS 6 release notes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html)   under the UIKit heading.

Answer (score 0):

It's `supportedInterfaceOrientations` on `UIViewController` you want to implement for iOS6 rather than `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.